time machine - move folder within time machine backup
So I have a time machine back. But I moved a folder 3.7TB from one location to another. I'd like to move that folder in the time machine backup but it doesn't allow me.
Why?

Since the folder is already on the time machine backup moving is significantly faster than doing a delete and time machine backup of 3.7 TB folder. This would save me days.

What I would like to do

folder1
move folder1 to time-machine-backup-latest-folder/folder2/folder1

Want I can do

Create and delete folders in time machine backup

What I can't do (finder complains)

sudo mv source destination
change time machine backup folder settings to admin read/write (through GUI) command+I admin from read to read/write
even enabling root I was still getting operation not permitted

Question:

How can I move that folder?


What version of macOS? What is the TM drive format - HFS+ or APFS?  APFS TM drives are read only and, for HFS+, you are playing with fire to attempt any modification.

@Gilby - macOS 10.11, journaled extended.  Got my oven mitts on.  :)

Since you seem determined to corrupt your backup, you could try using sudo /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/MacOS/bypass (I think that is in macOS 10.11)

How big is the total amount of data in your backup, if not 3.7 TB? I would hope that APFS wouldn't need to copy the data again; but otherwise your best option is to delete the "old" folder after it has copied.
